# Change background using selector in android

Tags: android, android-layout, android-activity

I need to change the background color of layout background based on click events. so created one selector and set background for layout.

XML code: bg.xml

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_pressed="true"
        android:drawable="@drawable/bg_tabselect" /> <!-- pressed -->
    <item android:state_focused="true"
        android:drawable="@drawable/bg_tabselect" /> <!-- focused -->
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/bg_tabunselect" /> <!-- default -->
</selector>
```

Layout: layoutmain.xml

```
<RelativeLayout
android:id="@+id/layout"
android:background="@drawable/bg.xml">
<Textview.../>
<Textview.../>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Java : Main.java

```
   RelativeLayout layout=(RelativeLayout)view.findviewbyid(R.id.layout);
    layout.setonclicklisteners(this);



     @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            switch (v.getId()){
                case R.id.layout:
                       Toast.makeText(getActivity(),"Selectedone",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                    break;
            }
        }
```

Problem:

> 1.when pressed on layout it working properly when remove press on layout again back to unselect color. How do solve this?
>   2. How to make first layout is default selection?

thanks in advance...

Comment: @maveň edited check once..

Comment: @ChiragSavsani drawable property is not there for Relative layout.

Comment: Sry use  background="@drawable/bg_tabselect"

Comment: @ChiragSavsani   if use tab select for background then how it change when unselect state?

Comment: Use `RadioButton` and add this line `android:button="@null"`. It will hide the circle image. Then change its background when clicked.

Comment: @activesince93 i have two textviews inside layout

Answer (score 0):

> when remove press on layout again back to unselect color

It's because you have two other items defined in your selector. and when the layout is not selected it goes to the default item, which is:

```
<item android:drawable="@drawable/bg_tabunselect" /> <!-- default -->
```

and about the second question, if you want background changes after click and do not turn back the the `bg_tabunselect` you can do something like this:

just remove the selector from the layout:

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/layout"
    android:background="@drawable/bg_tabunselect">
    <Textview.../>
    <Textview.../>
</RelativeLayout>
```

and then in your onclickListener just change the backgournd:

```
RelativeLayout layout=(RelativeLayout)view.findviewbyid(R.id.layout);
layout.setonclicklisteners(this);
 @Override
 public void onClick(View v) {
        switch (v.getId()){
            case R.id.layout:
                   Toast.makeText(getActivity(),"Selectedone",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                   layout.setBackground(R.drawable.bg_tabselect);
                break;
        }
    }
```

Comment: i have 3 layouts with same functionality in activity..like this maens need to set bg for all layouts..so selector is one option?

Comment: @sreekanth Yes i think so, As far as i understood you want to change the background after click and not turn back to the previous state so I think selector is not a good option for this problem ;)

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

<item android:state_selected="true" android:drawable="@drawable/bg_tabselect"/>
<item android:state_pressed="true" android:drawable="@drawable/bg_tabselect"/>
<item android:drawable="@drawable/bg_tabunselect"/>

</selector>
```

without

```
 android:state_focused
```

Comment: delete ".xml"             <RelativeLayout
android:id="@+id/layout"
android:background="@drawable/bg">
<Textview.../>
<Textview.../>
</RelativeLayout>